# Windows 7 text input/graphics repainting in random areas

Tags: windows-7, command-line, graphics-card, desktop-gadget

In the past few months I've been encountering this issue where the line of text being typed in the command prompt window reappears in a random place on screen and paints over whatever was previously in those pixels.  This is usually resolved by a system reboot, but then recurs a few hours to a few days later. I notice whenever this happens the Windows 7 gadgets automatically toggle between foreground, background, and a semi-transparent state.  Closing the gadgets did not solve the problem, so it appears to be another symptom and not a cause.  Scanned for viruses and came up clean.  Any ideas on what's causing this and how to resolve it permanently so work isn't being interrupted?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you're talking about?  Does the oddness show up in that screenshot?  If so, can you provide a public link to the screenshot image so we can see it?  Have you tried the basics, like updating your (video) drivers to the latest revision?